# Converting special characters (like \n) to their escaped versions

Tags: c++, c, string

How to convert for instance `"A\r\nB\tC\nD"` to `"A\\r\\nB\\tC\\nD"` in C(++)?

Ideally using standard library only and a bonus upvote for both pure C and pure C++ solutions.

Comment: what is the original string held in? And are the `\r`/`\n` for example characters (i.e. 0x0D and 0x0A) or character sequences (i.e. \ followed by n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, replace `char` with `wchar_t` and `std::string` with `std::wstring` if you're using wide character strings.

```
std::string input(/* ... */);
std::string output;
for(std::string::const_iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it)
{
    char currentValue = *it;
    switch (currentValue)
    {
    case L'\t':
        output.append("\\t");
        break;
    case L'\\':
        output.append("\\\\");
        break;
    //.... etc.
    default:
        output.push_back(currentValue);
    }
}
```

You can do this in C but it's going to be more difficult because you don't know the buffer size in advance (Though you can make a worst  case guess of 2 times the size of the original string). I.e.

```
//Disclaimer; it's been a while since I've written pure C, so this may
//have a bug or two.
const char * input = // ...;
size_t inputLen = strlen(input);
char * output = malloc(inputLen * 2);
const char * inputPtr = input;
char * outputPtr = output;
do
{
    char currentValue = *inputPtr;
    switch (currentValue)
    {
    case L'\t':
        *outputPtr++ = '\\';
        *outputPtr = 't';
        break;
    case L'\\':
        *outputPtr++ = '\\';
        *outputPtr = '\\';
        break;
    //.... etc.
    default:
        *outputPtr = currentValue;
    }
} while (++outputPtr, *inputPtr++);
```

(Remember to add error handling to the C version for things like malloc failures ;) )

Comment: That's why I was hoping for some library function; but thanks.

Comment: @mbq: Then just use the C++ version; I've been using it for years and know it doesn't have bugs :) (Hell, if you're in C++ then you **are** using `std::string`, right? :) )

Comment: @Bill Sure, unless I have to mess with C ones because of interacting some other code and the problem is simple, like strlen.

Comment: @mbq: Huh? I don't understand.

Comment: @Bill Like for instance you get one C-string from one C library and want to check its size before passing it to other C-string using library -- here conversion to std::string only to get length is an overhead. Such stuff happens with low level GUIs and networking.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something I came up with...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

inline char needs_escaping(char val) {
        switch(val) {
                case '\n': return 'n';
                case '\r': return 'r';
                case '\t': return 't';
        }
        return 0;
}

char *escape_string(char *in) {
        unsigned int needed = 0, j = 0, length = strlen(in), i;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if(needs_escaping(in[i])) needed++;
        }

        char *out = malloc(length + needed + 1);
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                char escape_val = needs_escaping(in[i]);
                if(escape_val) {
                        out[j++] = '\\';
                        out[j++] = escape_val;
                }
                else {
                        out[j++] = in[i];
                }
        }
        out[length + needed] = '\0';    
        return out;
}

int main() {
        char *in  = "A\r\nB\tC\nD";
        char *out = escape_string(in);
        printf("%s\n", out);
        free(out);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for interesting solution using array indexes instead of pointers (though if you use this in real code please amortize the `strlen` calls -- no need for order n-squared time complexity for a method like this).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's any standard library function that does this directly.  The most efficient way would be simply to iterate over the input buffer character by character, conditionally copying into an output buffer, with some special state-machine logic to handle `'\'`, etc.

I'm sure there are ways to do this with various combinations of `strchr()` et al, but it will probably be less efficient in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a lookup table of 32 `const char*` literals, one for every control code (ASCII 0 to ASCII 31). I would then iterate over the original string, copying non-control chars (ASCII >= 32) to the output buffer and substituting values from the lookup table for ASCII 0--31.

Note 1: ASCII 0 is obviously special for C strings (not so for C++.)

Note 2: The lookup table would contain C escape sequences for codes that have them (`\n`, `\r` etc) and backslash plus hex/octal/decimal codes for those that don't.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm in C#. Maybe you can treat it like pseudo-code and convert it to C++.

public static string EscapeChars(string Input)
{
    string Output = "";

```
foreach (char c in Input)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '\n':
            Output += "\\n";
            break;
        case '\r':
            Output += "\\r";
            break;
        case '\t':
            Output += "\\t";
            break;
        default:
            Output += c;
            break;
    }                
}
return Output;
```

}

Comment: This algorithm doesn't work. `\n` for example, is not going to be converted, because `\n` doesn't actually have a slash in the source string. This will turn "\\n" into "\\\\n" instead.

Comment: I respectfully beg to differ. I actually ran this before I posted. Just tried with \\n as Input and it works as expected - it outputs \\n not \\\\n. The switch...case statement ensures that double-slashes aren't included in the output, because the current character (c) has to be an "escape character".

Comment: @Bob: But that's my point. The input is not "\n", it's a newline character, which doesn't have a slash. Example program: http://pastebin.com/M2b1Mv4w

Comment: Disclaimer - I ran this as C#, which I probably have no business doing since this was a C++ question. ;-)

Comment: @Bob: The link I posted was C# as well -- it's wrong in either language.

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean *slaps head*. Duh. I haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: @Bob: Almost there lol -- you've got two too many slashes on your literals in that method. :) Perhaps http://pastebin.com/dXSzkZac is what you're looking for? :)

Comment: You're kidding me. ROFL. I have no idea what I was thinking. Updated answer (again).