# How to interpret backslashes in a string?

Tags: c, string, escaping

I can find some guidance for this question for things like Bash, but not for C:

I'm working with a string that contains the body of an email message and I noticed that it wasn't formatting the body, since it was using `fprintf`:

`fprintf(p, "%s", body);`

So, I went ahead and changed that to this, thinking it would solve the problem:

`fwrite(body, sizeof(char), strlen(body), p);`

I noticed that if defined a string and passed the pointer right in, the formatting indeed worked:

```
char *c = "Some string\n\twith escape\r\nsequences."
fwrite(c, sizeof(char), strlen(c), p);
```

I did a hex dump of my strings to compare, and realized that the string didn't have the escape characters themselves, but rather string representations of them - that is instead of `0d`, I had `5c` and `72` as two separate bytes.

I can't change the way that the string is being received, so somehow I need to be able to interpret the escape sequences in the string, almost as if it were a format string. What is the proper way to do this in C? I don't want to do anything like looking for `\` `n` and replace it with `\n`... the entire string itself should just be parsed as if that were the string literal itself from the program.

What would be the best way to do this? This is not for literal strings but for dynamic user input.

Comment: When you make a literal string, if you want a backslash in the string you need to put `\\` into that literal string (otherwise it will do the conversion) but that is for literal strings only - when you read data from some input source the characters are what they are.  So if you want to convert a string that contains the characters `\` and `n` to a linefeed you need to write a function to do that.

Comment: Here are some almost identical question:s  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817807/converting-escape-sequence-in-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377320/converting-special-characters-like-n-to-their-escaped-versions

Comment: Here is another: that might have good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369344/how-to-unescape-strings-in-c-c

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Hmm... I guess it sounds like there is no "the way", it's a completely manual process. I guess I will go ahead and write my own simple helper, I was sure there had to be a more "official" way to do it though...

Comment: @InterLinked Do you want "How to interpret backslashes in a string?" or "How to interpret backslashes in source code?"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The former

Comment: InterLinked There are _no_ escape sequences nor a back-slash in the _string_: `"Some string\n\twith escape\r\nsequences."`.  There are escape sequences in the source code.  "I had 5c and 72 as two separate bytes" --> then you are not doing a hexdump of the _string_.

Comment: "What is the proper way to do this in C? I don't want to do anything like looking for \ n and replace it with \n" is unclear.  Do you want the proper way or not look for a backslash - choose one.